# Permission denied once code is changed

Tags: python, permissions

I'm still a newb to this, so sorry if I mess up :D

So I'm trying to write a script that goes through some .xml files to get certain lines and put's them into an excel sheet.

Code:

```
import os
import openpyxl


def main():
    print_header()
    folder = get_folder_from_user()
    if not folder:
        print("Sorry, that folder doesn't exist.")
        return

    text = get_search_text_from_user()
    if not text:
        print("Sorry, I can't search for nothing.")
        return
    count = input("Show match count? y/n")
    name = "output.xlsx"
    # name = input("Name for workbook: ")

    x = []
    output = search_file(folder, text)
    match_count = 0
    for i in output:
        match_count += 1
        string = i
        string = string.split(">")
        string = string[1]
        string = string.split("<")
        string = string[0]
        i = string
        print(i)
        x.extend([i])
    write_to_workbook(name, x)

    if count == "y":
        print("==================")
        print("Found {} matches".format(match_count))
        print("==================")


def write_to_workbook(name, x):
    wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
    ws = wb.active
    a = 1
    ws.append(x)
    wb.save("C:/Users/Kevin/Desktop/{}".format(name))
    a += 1


def print_header():
    print("-----------------------------------")
    print("----------File Search App----------")
    print("-----------------------------------")
    print()


def get_folder_from_user():
    folder = input("Which folder do you want to search? ")
    if not folder or not folder.strip():
        return None

    if not os.path.isdir(folder):
        return None

    return os.path.abspath(folder)


def get_search_text_from_user():
    print("Which data do you want me to copy for you?")
    print("[1]SeqTest Read")
    print("[2]SeqTest Write")
    print("[3]Random 4K1TTest Read")
    print("[4]Random 4K1TTest Write")
    print("[5]Random 4K64TTest Read")
    print("[6]Random 4K64TTest Write")
    print("[7]AccTimeTest Read")
    print("[8]AccTimeTest Write")
    print("[9]Score")
    print("[0]All")
    choice = int(input("Choose now: "))

    if choice == 1:
        line = 15
    elif choice == 2:
        line = 16
    elif choice == 3:
        line = 19
    elif choice == 4:
        line = 20
    elif choice == 5:
        line = 23
    elif choice == 6:
        line = 24
    elif choice == 7:
        line = 27
    elif choice == 8:
        line = 28
    elif choice == 9:
        line = 99
    elif choice == 0:
        line = 100
    else:
        line = 0
    line = 15
    return int(line)


def search_folders(folder, line):
    items = os.listdir(folder)

    for item in items:
        full_item = os.path.join(folder, item)
        if os.path.isdir(full_item):
            yield from search_folders(full_item, line)
        else:
            yield from search_file(full_item, line)


def search_file(filename, line):
    with open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as fin:

        lines = fin.readlines()

    if line == 99:
        print(lines[31])
        print(lines[32])
        print(lines[33])
        yield ("/n".join(lines[31:34]))
    elif line == 100:
        s = 0
        while s < 10:

            print(filename)
            print(lines[4])
            if line == 15 or 16:
                print("Seq")
                if line == 15:
                    print("Read")
                else:
                    print("Write")
            elif line == 19 or 20:
                print("4k ")
                if line == 19:
                    print("Read")
                else:
                    print("Write")
            elif line == 23 or 24:
                print("4k 64")
                if line == 23:
                    print("Read")
                else:
                    print("Write")
            elif line == 27 or 28:
                print("Acc")
                if line == 27:
                    print("Read")
                else:
                    print("Write")
            elif line == 99:
                print("")
            yield (lines[line])
    else:
        print(filename)
        print(lines[4])
        if line == 15 or 16:
            print("Seq")
            if line == 15:
                print("Read")
            else:
                print("Write")
        elif line == 19 or 20:
            print("4k ")
            if line == 19:
                print("Read")
            else:
                print("Write")
        elif line == 23 or 24:
            print("4k 64")
            if line == 23:
                print("Read")
            else:
                print("Write")
        elif line == 27 or 28:
            print("Acc")
            if line == 27:
                print("Read")
            else:
                print("Write")
        elif line == 99:
            print("")
        yield (lines[line])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

In short:
User has to type in the directory with the text files.
Then the wanted lines are chosen. (Fixed to line 15 for testing. I didn't get to the point to fix a problem when I want every line specified in the selection).
The user is then asked if he wants the total amount of matches.
Then it runs through all the text files and outputs line 15 of every file (just some data from ssd benchmarks).
The data is denn written into an excel file.
The code is working mostly. I still have to figure out how to properly output the data to excel (format is not as I want it).
But the problem is that the permissions to the directory change as soon as I add this Code:

```
def trigger_search(filename, line):
    xyz = search_file(filename, line)
    return xyz
```

As soon as I add this I get an errno 13: Permission denied.
It can't access the directory with the .xml files anymore.
Even if I delete the added code, I still get this error.
Only workaround is to copy the "unchanged" code (without the trigger_search) and overwrite the .py file.
Just copy paste and it works fine (no matter how often I run the code).

Any hint why this happens and how to fix this?

Please don't be too harsh because of the code, I know it's really newbie like. It'll be made properly as soon as it works :D

Comment: Have you actually tried looking at the permission? If yes, can you post them before and after running the script.

Comment: You have never closed the file. Try closing it.

Comment: The permission on the directory are set to write-protection. I turned that off again and again, but it shows as protected again. But as I said the code can still access it if it's unchanged. 
The file is closed all the time, I know that it can't access it if it's open

Comment: Adding the code from trigger_search doesn't trigger the error.
Only when I change the code like this in main method:
output = search_file(filename, line)
TO
output = trigger_search(filename, line)

then I get the error.
If I switch it back I still get the error, even removing everything from trigger_search doesn't fix it. I have to copy paste the code the fix it. It doesn't make sense to me. If I delete trigger_search it's the exact same code that is copy pasted

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind guys.
I'm just dumb.

in the trigger_search I had to use search_folders, not search_file.
When changing the code back, I also replaced it with search_file although it was search_folders before in main method..

Using the right method actually works.
I'm so sorry...

Answer (score 0):

The reason here that it is returning an error is because you have not run it as an administrator. Before I show you how to solve the problem, you will either need to be an administrator on your computer or you will have to know the password of an administrator. Also, this answer assumes that you are running Windows on your computer.

**2 WAYS IF YOU RAN THIS PROGRAM FROM CMD**

- There are two ways to do this. The first way is to run the program "Run" (it was automatically installed by Windows), then type in cmd.exe. The second way is to tap the Windows key and look up cmd, and right-click the button that says "Command Prompt", and click on the button that says "Run as administrator".
- The second way is to open the Command Prompt, and type in runas /profile /user:administrator “insert\path\here\program.py” where "administrator" should be replaced with your username on the computer, and "insert\path\here" should be replaced with the path where your program is in, and "program.py" should be replaced with the name of your program (if you are in the same directory as the program, then you do not need to include the path.)

**1 WAY IF YOU RAN THIS PROGRAM FROM THE WINDOWS SEARCH BAR**

- When in the Windows Search Bar (at the bottom-left), then search up your program's filename (for example, "program.py") then right-click it and click the button that says "Run as adminstrator".

Comment: Hi and thanks for the answer.
I am the administrator on my computer^^
The code can actually access the file without running it with privileges.
It's just like that:
Code:
a
b
c

works fine. as soon as I do like:
Code:
a
d
b
c

It can't access it anymore. Deleting the D doesn't change anything.
I have to copy paste the code again (exactly as it is when having this error).
I'm not closing the .py or anything. I just overwrite ABC with ABC and it works again...

edit: I'm working with pycharm